# HazelCast Warning : Resetting heartbeat timestamps because of huge system clock jump! Clock-Jump: -4446 ms, Heartbeat-Timeout: 5000 ms

Tags: hazelcast

Im getting a exception as : Resetting heartbeat timestamps because of huge system clock jump! Clock-Jump: -4446 ms, Heartbeat-Timeout: 5000 ms ,In a three node cluster .
What could have caused the issue to get this warn : Hazelcast version : 3.6.5

Comment: Please try to format your question again. It's not really clear what this stuff is about.

Comment: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/7455

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is something that stops the JVM - swapping, a long GC pause, attaching a debugger, or floating the machine image to another host on virtualised infrastructure.

Check the `gc.log`, and post this if you can.

Comment: System time difference  between node will cause this ?

Comment: Possibly, there can be many causes. Is the issue still occuring for you ?

Comment: I have the same issue even if I am using only one node

Comment: @Hicham is the system clock jumping or long GCs ?

Comment: @Neil Stevenson The system clock is not jumping. Please, how can I check GC?

Comment: @Hicham If you're on a new version, just enable [Diagnotics](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#diagnostics)